# How to traverse a matrix functionally in JavaScript ES6?

Tags: javascript, matrix, foreach, functional-programming

Here is my code submission for the challenge 'Staircase' on Hackerrank:

```js
function staircase(n) {
    // fill() fills out `undefined` items, which helps to initiate new n*n matrix 
    let matrix = Array(n).fill().map(() => Array(n).fill());

    matrix.forEach((curArr, idY) => {
        curArr.forEach((curVal, idX) => {
            curVal = (idX + idY + 1 >= n) ? '#' : ' ';
            process.stdout.write(curVal);
        }, [])
        console.log();
    }, []);
}
```

When I tested with `staircase(6)`, I did get the expected result:

```js
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

However, when I modify the code to inspect `matrix` like this:

```js
function staircase(n) {
    // fill() fills out `undefined` items, which helps to initiate new n*n matrix 
    let matrix = Array(n).fill().map(() => Array(n).fill());

    matrix.forEach((curArr, idY) => {
        curArr.forEach((curVal, idX) => {
            curVal = (idX + idY + 1 >= n) ? '#' : ' ';
        }, [])
    }, []);

    console.log(matrix);
}
```

Here's what I get:

```
[ [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ],
  [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ],
  [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ],
  [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ],
  [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ],
  [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ] ]
```

So my questions are:

1. Why is `matrix` not modified?
2. Are there any purely functional way of solving this problem (i.e using only `map()` ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do.

```js
const array = (length, lookup) => Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => lookup(i));

const string = (separator, length, lookup) => array(length, lookup).join(separator);

const staircase = n =>
    console.log(
        string("\n", n, i =>
            string("", n, j =>
                i + j < n - 1 ? ' ' : '#')));

staircase(9);
```

Apart from the `console.log`, the `staircase` function is pure.

Comment: I absolutely love this solution, as it signifies that in this `staircase` problem, index references of temporary array are the main concern for manipulation, not the value references. Thanks for this intuitive solution!

Answer (score 0):

1. cause of the problem

`curVal` is value type, not reference type. Value in `matrix` doesn't modified because `curVal` is just a copy.

one solution: change `curVal = (idX + idY + 1 >= n) ? '#' : ' ';` into `matrix[idY][idX] = (idX + idY + 1 >= n) ? '#' : ' '`

2. use `map`

```
[...Array(n).keys()].map((ignore, y)=>[...Array(n).keys()].map((ignore, x)=>(x+y+2>n)?'#':' '))
```

Comment: It took me a while to understand what the spread operator does here! Thank you, this is brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

The main point of your exercise is to decide whether to print a `#` or an empty space... which is based on the difference between column index and row index (`j >= i`).

```js
const staircase = (length) => Array.from({ length }, (_, x) => 
  Array.from({ length }, (_, y) => y >= length - 1 - x ? '#' : ' ').join('')
)
  .join('\n');


console.log(
  staircase(10),
);
```

---

on your example:

```
    matrix.forEach((curArr, idY) => {
        curArr.forEach((curVal, idX) => {
            curVal = (idX + idY + 1 >= n) ? '#' : ' ';
        }, [])
    }, []);
```

as stated by others, you cannot directly modify `curVal` since it is not passed by reference, try to use `Array#map` instead:

```
curArr.map((curVal, idX) => 'somethingElse')
```